# Number of ordered set partitions with subset size $\leq 3$

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, integer-partitions, combinatorial-proofs, set-partition

For $n \ge 0$, let $h_n$ be the number of ways of taking $n$ (distinguishable)
rabbits, putting them into identical cages with one to three rabbits per
cage and then ordering the cages in a row. Find an exponential generating
function for $h_n$ (assuming $h_0 = 1$).

I know if the ordering of the cages does not matter, then generating function would be $h_n = h_{n-1}+(n-1)h_{n-2}+(n-2)(n-1)h_{n-3}$. How can I include the ordering of the cages in the function?

Comment: Why not calculate a few values of $h_n$ and look for a pattern? (or look them up in the OEIS?)

Comment: What you have written down as a generating function is no such thing. What you have written down is a recurrence relation. A generating function is something of the form $\sum h_nx^n/n!$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I computed the first nine values of $h_n$ $(n\geq1)$ recursively and obtained the sequence
$$  1, 3, 13, 74, 530, 4550, 45570, 521640, 6717480\ .$$
This is sequence [A189886](http://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C%203%2C%2013%2C%2074%2C%20530%2C%204550%2C%2045570%2C%20521640%2C%206717480&language=english&go=Search) in OEIS. There is a reference to sequences of sets, no set containing more than three elements. But I didn't study the details.

Comment: You'll find both a linear recurrence relation and an exponential generating function at that page. But maybe http://oeis.org/A189886 is a better link for it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do you mind to explain why the generating function is $1/(1 - x - x^2/2! - x^3/3!) $? I get that the denominator is for a block with size 1-3, but why is it an inverse?

Comment: There are links and references at that OEIS page. Have you followed them up, wtnmath, to see whether they derive the exponential generating function?

Comment: So, any follow-up, wtnmath?